# How to deal with differently skewed biological data?

Tags: normal-distribution, modeling, skewness, signal-detection

I have a single-cell data set with around 40 variables per cell (protein expression, all variables are measured simultaneously). The expression distributions for the single channels look quite different. After log-transformation, some look gaussian distributed, others are skewed or even multimodal distributed (see histograms). How should I deal with this kind of data?

What I want to do is basically to detect significant expression for the different channels for every cell. For the gaussian distributed expression, I can easily scale the data and use probability distribution function to infer p-values. However, this is not possible for channels with skewed data or data that follow a multimodal distribution.

Any suggestions on modeling approaches, data normalization/transformation that might work with such data?

[image]

Comment: A quantile regression might be helpful for you: https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1890/1540-9295%282003%29001%5B0412%3AAGITQR%5D2.0.CO%3B2

Answer (score 1):

If I had seen protein expression data with multimodality in the log-transform, I would be very, *very* careful. Log-scaling is not *just* for convenience, it has a lot in common with the concept of concentrations. A multimodal pattern would make me suspect there's a bunch of **heterogenous subpopulations** in the sample.

For example, you could be seeing two types of cells with different **baseline expression** patterns, or different **propensity** towards some treatment (e.g. drug uptake through the membrane), or different **response** to some treatment (e.g. the number of nuclear receptors for some drug => more translation as a result of the treatment).

You say your dataset is single-cell data, but the same principle holds. Might be different organelles, I suppose? Also, you're using marker measurements, something might be dimming the signal from the marker in some fraction of the protein...

Basically, *some* hidden variable is separating the two peaks you see on the histogram, otherwise they'd be a nice log-Gaussian. Whatever it is, this is a huge potential landmine. You could explain it away (probably using some hierarchical approach) or ignore it (and just take the mean of the two), but both impose a personal interpretation on what you see in the data.

One particular tricky case would be that you *already* have a high-expression subpopulation, and any treatment would just shift the measurements towards the right peak, and if you had simply averaged them together, you'd only see a slight increase in the skew.

Comment: There can be true heterogeneity in protein expression among individual cells that morphologically appear similar, an area of considerable research interest. That said, you are correct that there are "huge potential landmines" that require attention to the sources of the underlying data, not just simple statistical analysis (+1). In particular, if the data shown are flow-cytometry results, the lower peaks might represent the distribution of background fluorescence rather than actual protein expression. That could be an important technical problem that must be resolved first.

Comment: Indeed, the data set contains cells from different organ systems. This most likely explains the observed distribution structures. I will try to separate data according to the tissue, I think this might be a good start. Data is actually from Mass Cytometry and not Flow. Background fluorescence is therefore not a problem. However, unspecific binding of antibodies could cause a similar effect.